# создание ToolBar в Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-toolbar

Создаю активити на нем фрагмент, а в фрагменте должен быть ToolBar! 
Но его нет! Делаю так

**Активити:**

```
public class MainGridActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MainGridFragment mainGridFragment;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    private final String MAIN_DRID_FRAGMENT_TAG = "MAIN_DRID_FRAGMENT_TAG";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        onInflateActivity();



    }



    private void onInflateActivity(){
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mainGridFragment = (MainGridFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(MAIN_DRID_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if(mainGridFragment == null){
            mainGridFragment = new MainGridFragment();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.main_grid_conteiner, mainGridFragment, MAIN_DRID_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();

        }
    }
}
```

**его леяут:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/main_tool_bar" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**Фрагмент:**

```
public class MainGridFragment extends Fragment{

    private AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_grid_list, null);
    setToolBar();
   return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_grid_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}


public Toolbar generateToolBar(){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_tool_bar, null);

    return (Toolbar)v;
}

private void setToolBar(){
    appCompatActivity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    appCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(generateToolBar());

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/main_tool_bar" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**Сам ToolBar:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_tool_bar"
    style="@style/main_tool_bar"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Вроде все так! Может что-то пропустил?
Подскажите в чем ошибка моя !!
Спасибо!**

Comment: Ну... у вас у тулбара высота/ширина не прописаны... Может в этом дело.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, они в стилях прописаны (

Comment: А если setToolBar(); вызвать в onResume фрагмента?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не изменилось !! Результат тот же (
isShowing() - дает true ! Но не понимаю почему его не видно

Comment: А если не пользовать include?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, пустой фрагмент !

Comment: Вы, кстати, не добавляете же вообще тулбар в разметку, а генерируете новый в setToolBar. При этом в разметку его не добавляете...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, если можно, напишите, пожалуйста ответ! Просто не до конца понял ваше замечание !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. У вас есть тулбар в разметке фрагмента но вы его нигде не используете.
2. Устанавливать тулбар экшнбаром активити надо не раньше чем разметка создана. Т.е. в onResume()
3. В вашем методе setToolBar вы создаёте новый экземпляр класса ToolBar и назначаете его экшнбаром активити. Но этот ToolBar ни в чью разметку не добавлен. Попробуйте вместо создания нового устанавливать тот тулбар, коий у вас в разметке уже есть.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое ! Очень благодарен за помощь!